# get the string value only when it is set c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, get, set, system.reactive

in the get set property return the value only after the value is set. I have used reactive library and subscribed to message it runs on a different thread. when the event is raised and value is set capture the value and return.

```
 internal PinMessage()
        {
            obj.PinsAvailable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(HandlePinsAvailable);
        }      

        private void HandlePinsAvailable(byte[] pinBytes)
        {
           pinmesssage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pinBytes);           
        }

        public void Readvalue(object stringobj)
        {
            pinmesssage = (string)stringobj;
        }

        internal string GetPinMessage(string AccoutNumber)
        {
            string pinstring = string.Empty;
            obj.SendPinRequest(AccoutNumber);
            t1.Join();
            pinstring = pinmesssage;
            return pinstring;
        }

        private string _pinMessafe;

        public string pinmesssage
        {
            get
            {
//Get value only when the property is set
                return _pinMessafe;
            }
            set { _pinMessafe = value; }
        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If it's a string, just check to see if `_pinMessafe` is null/empty and only return if false.

Comment: @tnw suppose you checked it and it is not null, and before you return it, a different thread set it to null.

Comment: I get the pinmesssage from a device, by the time I get the data the GetPinMessage is returning a null. It is not waiting for the pinmessage.

Comment: You're trying to use Rx to do a synchronous code. That's not what it is for. You need to refactor this code to be asynchronous. There's also a serious disconnect between having one observable and multiple requests for pin messages. You need to pair them up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait on another thread setting a value you can use a [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx)

You create a TaskCompletionSource somewhere

```
TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
```

On the thread that generates the value you do

```
tcs.SetResult("some string message");
```

On the thread waiting for the result you do

```
string message = tcs.Task.Result; // Will block the current thread
```

or better use [async await pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) in an async method

```
string message = await tcs.Task
```

However if you are really using [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) Then you should
probably be using it for the whole pipeline rather than the above pattern. 
You probably should be writing

```
string message = await MessageSource().Take(1);
```

where MessageSource would have the signiture

```
IObservable<string> MessageSource();
```

Comment: this is really useful I can not vote for it, I am a newbie. The reason I needed it I have asynchronous  threads I have to synchronous them into one single method. so that I can return a value once I send the message in a method. Currently I am using onObserve and when the data is available is retrieve it. I am building a library where I send the message and receive the data CLASSIC STYLE

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a lot of stuff here. When you use Rx you don't try to marshall threads by doing thread joins. You don't move in and out of the Rx code.

Your code should probably look something like this:

```
internal IObservable<string> GetPinMessage(string AccoutNumber)
{
    return Observable
        .Start(() => obj.SendPinRequest(AccoutNumber))
        .Select(pinBytes => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pinBytes))
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);
}
```

I've assumed that `SendPinRequest` is a synchronous request. Rx will turn this into a single valued asynchronous observable for you.